# Multiple stacks of coins, take turns removing either one or all from any of the stacks, who will get the last turn, A or B?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

this is a variation of the coin pile removing game that I have seen in various places online. In this case the properties are as such:

There are n stacks of coins all potentially different sizes. Starting with Player A, the players A and B take turns removing either one or all the coins from one of the stacks. The person left with no turn possible loses. How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: You start looking for $P$ (won by the previous player) and $N$(won by the next player) positions.  An $N$ position is one that can move to a $P$ position.  A $P$ position is one that can only move to $N$ positions.  Start with small positions and build up, looking for a pattern.  You could read about Nim and the Sprague-Grundy theorem.  As a perfect information impartial game, it is Nim in disguise in that every position can be equated to a Nim-stack.  Finding the correspondence can be hard.

Comment: I'm still a little confused would you be able to clarify these examples?

 So would any single pile be an N position?

Following up, if you have two piles of one coin each, that would be a P position? Then, with two piles of equal size, that would be a P position?

Again, as more followup, would just xor-ing the size of the piles and checking for them to equal zero fail?

Comment: Well, xor-ing just fails in the case of 3 piles with 3 coins each

Comment: Yes, a single pile is N because you can take it all and two equal piles are P because the second player can mirror the first.  XORing fails because 1+n is P if n is odd because anybody who takes the 1 loses, so both players take a coin at a time from the large stack.  You get down to 1+1, which is P.

Comment: If you can find a collection of piles that is P, you can ignore it.  A player who is winning in the rest can only move in that collection when his opponent does and keep that collection P.   Your 3+3+3 example works this way. Two of the piles make a P position, the third is N, so the whole thing is N.  This shows any position that is a+a+b is N-just take the b pile.

Comment: XORing works for classic Nim, but not for this game as you have shown.

Comment: So then, would you have the following cases?:


  evenPile oddPile = N |


  oddPile evenPile = N |


  evenPile evenPile = P |


  oddPile oddPile = P |


Now, would i have to examine the cases N-odd, N-even, P-odd, P-even or just split the piles into subsets of 2? I am confused on how to extend the simple case analysis into n piles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompted by Théophile's answer, we can make a direct statement of how to play the game.  We claim the $P$ positions, won by the previous player, are those that have an even number of piles with an even number of stones and an even number of piles that have an odd number of stones, and the $N$ positions are the rest.  To prove this we need to show that the terminal position is $P$, that all moves from $P$ positions result in $N$ positions, and that every $N$ position has at least one move to a $P$ position.  The terminal position has no piles, so has an even number of piles of each parity.  From a $P$ position, any move will leave an odd number of piles of the parity moved in.  If the move leaves stones in the pile moved in, it will also leave an odd number of piles of the other parity, but we don't need that.  If there are an odd number of piles of one parity and an even number of the other, take an entire pile of the parity with an odd number of piles and this will leave a $P$ position.  If there are an odd number of piles of each parity, take one stone from a pile with an even number of stones and this will leave a $P$ position.  This shows the $N$ and $P$ positions are as claimed and gives a specific move where there is a winning one (the $N$ positions).

Answer (score 2):

This game is similar to [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) and can be solved using the [Sprague-Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem).

We can calculate the Nim-values of the stacks in your game by looking at the choices available and finding the *minimal excluded element*, or *mex*.

Let $v(n)$ be the Nim-value of a stack of size $n$. Then:

- A pile of size $1$ can only be reduced to $0$; $v(1) = mex(\{0\})=*$.
- A pile of size $2$ can be reduced to $0$ or $1$; $v(2) = mex(\{0,v(1)\})=*2$.
- A pile of size $3$ can be reduced to $0$ or $2$; $v(3) = mex(\{0,v(2)\})=*$.
- A pile of size $4$ can be reduced to $0$ or $3$; $v(4) = mex(\{0,v(3)\})=*2$.
- $\ldots$

In short, we can look at each pile as being either *empty*, *even*, or *odd*.

Comment: It's a variant of nim since you may take just one coin or a whole pile. Does the wikipedia page discuss that variant? If not, you'd have to construct the Sprague-Grundy function yourself.

Comment: @Théophile I am still a little confused regarding your statement. Do you mean a pile of size 1 or that we have 1 pile, 2 piles, 3 piles, and so on?

Comment: @BobMarley This is all looking at individual piles. So a pile of size $4$, say, has the value $*2$. If you have multiple piles, you can analyze the game by adding the nimbers associated with them. For example, if there are three piles with sizes $4,5$, and $6$, then the value of the whole is $*2 + * + *2 = *$. This is a win for the next player to move (who wins by taking one stone from the middle pile, or that entire pile).

Comment: @Théophile:  taking one stone from the 5 in 4+5+6 loses.  That leaves 4+4+6 and I take all of the 6 to win.  A winning position is one that has an even number of even piles and an even number of odd piles.  Once you find the odd piles are * and the even ones are *2 the usual Nim addition or XOR rules apply.

Comment: Wait, so the solution is as simple as assigning * or *2 to each of the piles and applying xor 1 xor 2 to all the resulting values? And doesn't player 1 automatically win 4,5,6 with best play?

Comment: @RossMillikan and if that is the method, do you interpret any xor!=0 as player 1 win and any xor == 0 as player 2 win?

Comment: @Théophile also, looking at the case 4, 6:

we have *2 + *2 = *3 or *2?

Comment: @BobMarley if you are going to xor you take * as 1 and *2 as 2, and xor them all. This is the same as my even number of piles of each parity. 4,5,6 is a next player win by taking the 5. Taking one from the 5 is losing

Comment: @RossMillikan And to clarify, if I am only interested in if player A or player B wins, then whenever the xor of everything is NOT 0, player A wins and when it is, player B wins right?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, thanks for catching my mistake (again). The only winning move indeed is to remove all stones from the pile of 5.

Comment: @BobMarley A position with value 0 is a losing position. Any position with a non-zero value is winning because it can be reduced in one move to 0. The trick is to find which move does that. (In my example above, the winning move is to remove all stones from the pile of 5, leaving 4 and 6. This leaves for the next player $*2+*2=0$, i.e., a loss.)

Comment: @Théophile So would the case every pop up where there is a position with non-zero value, but there is no possible way to reduce it to zero? If not, then would the following algorithm identify (every time for n piles) whether player 1 or player 2 wins?

if(position at initial state has value 0) -> player 2 wins | 

else ->player 1 wins

Comment: @BobMarley Every non-zero position can be reduced to zero on the next move (although there might be other moves as well). If the overall position is non-zero, the next player to move wins by reducing it to zero. If the position is already zero, the next player to move loses.